# Embedding an Image album from third party (imgur, picasa)

Tags: javascript, html, image, embed

I'm looking for a free image hosting site that lets you upload/organize images by album (preferably with a massive album size), and then allows you to embed those albums into your own website/blog.

Imgur allows you to create albums but it seems to be used to hotlink to single images or link to the album on their site. Also picasa allows you to link albums but only the album cover then it navigates to their site.

Answer (score 0):

flickr.com.
Also, smugmug.com, which is probably one of the best, but their plans are paid.
Good luck.